# SharePoint 2013 - update item in Current Item - triggers multiple instance of sharepoint workflows

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-designer

I have a infopath library and i have multiple workflows in it (close to 6 workflows). one of them is sharepoint 2013  workflow and others are sharepoint 2010 workflow. when the sharepoint 2013 workflow runs (on create and on item modified) it has a line called update item in Current Item. i think this like is triggering 3 instances of all the workflows. how can we restrict all the workflows to be run only once.

Comment: i have already unchecked the Automatically update the workflow status to the current stage name checkbox